# Primeng Multiselect drop down inconsistent behaviour

Tags: angular, primeng, multi-select

I am having a primeng multiselect dropdown whose value is changed based on a selection from another dropdown.

```
<p-dropdown id="test" name="test" [style]="{'width':'100%'}"
 [(ngModel)]="selectedState" [options]="states" (onChange)="getCities()">
    </p-dropdown>
```

on selection of the above drop down triggers a function getCities() which is a rest end point that fetches the corresponding cities for a state. The cities value is populated on to the below multiselect drop down. The selectedCities may contain already selected values. So if a list of city does not contain any selectedCities the multiselect drop down comes in a weird state .

```
<p-multiSelect  id="names" name="names" [style]="{'width':'100%'}"
 [options]="cities" [(ngModel)]="selectedCities" (ngModelChange)="onModelChange()">
</p-multiSelect>
```

Thanks in advance. [image]

Comment: In my opinion, since the cities dropdown depends on state dropdown. Whenever the state dropdown's value is changed, `selectedCities` have to be reset. Hence the selected cities' value is guaranteed existed in the options of state dropdown.

Comment: But if i am resetting it,  how can i preserve the previously selected selectedCities ?.

Comment: Please update your question with `getCities()` and `onModelChange()`, then we can see what's overwriting and what could be refactored.

Comment: Another temp variable to hold previously selected value? But need to know why you need to save the previously selected value and how you going to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that you overwrite `selectedCities` but you with wish to keep previous selectedCities. `selectedCities` needs to hold latest `cities` + previous selections. Let's just update selectedCities on need basis.

Without seeing `getCities()` it's hard to know what's going on, but I'm guessing it returns `data` of cities. We flush `cities` and give it only the current selection.We use `concat` to add two arrays `selectedCities` and new`data` together. We use spread `...` to update the array and trigger template update. We use new Set to make sure we don't add duplicates on cities.

```js
getCities() {
this.cities = this.selectedCities;
this.cities = [...new Set(this.cities.concat(data))];
}
```

```js
onSelectDeselectCity(event: any) {
if (this.selectedCities.includes(event.value) { // remove
    this.selectedCities.splice(this.selectedCities.indexOf(event.value), 1);
} else {
    this.selectedCities.push(event.value) // add
  }
}
```

```js
<p-multiSelect  id="names" name="names" [style]="{'width':'100%'}"
 [options]="cities" [(ngModel)]="selectedCities" (ngModelChange)="onSelectDeselectCity($event)">
</p-multiSelect>
```